# Laravel query from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-8

I have four table in my Laravel project. There are "assets", "income", "expense", "ownerequities". Every table has some common columns:

```
id, ref, transaction_type, payment_type, amount, transaction_date
```

I want data from all tables with common columns `where payment_type = Cash`. And I want it ordered ascending or descending by `transaction_date`.

How can I write a query for this in my laravel 8.12?

```
public function getDayBook()
{
    $expenses = DB::table('expenses')->where('payment_type', 'Cash')->select('expense_date as date', 'ref', 'description', 'amount');

    $asset = DB::table('assets')->where('payment_type', 'Cash')->select('asset_date as date', 'ref', 'description', 'amount');

    $liablility = DB::table('liabilities')->where('payment_type', 'Cash')->select('liability_date as date', 'ref', 'description', 'amount');

    $equity=DB::table('ownerequities')->where('payment_type','Cash')->select('equity_date as date','ref','description','amount');

$query=DB::table('incomes')
->select('income_date as date','ref','description','amount')->where('payment_type','Cash')
->union($expenses)
->union($asset)
->union($liablility)
->union($equity)
->orderBy('date','DESC');
 return view('daybook.cash')->with('data', $query);

}
```

Comment: Please don't add `(Solve)` to your title. If you have a solution, please post it in the answers section below.

Comment: And what is the *specific* problem with the current code you presented?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function getDayBook()
        {
    
        $expenses = DB::table('expenses')->where('payment_type', 'Cash')->select('expense_date as date', 'ref', 'description', 'amount');
    
        $asset = DB::table('assets')->where('payment_type', 'Cash')->select('asset_date as date', 'ref', 'description', 'amount');
    
        $liablility = DB::table('liabilities')->where('payment_type', 'Cash')->select('liability_date as date', 'ref', 'description', 'amount');
    
        $equity=DB::table('ownerequities')->where('payment_type','Cash')->select('equity_date as date','ref','description','amount');
    
$query=DB::table('incomes')
->select('income_date as date','ref','description','amount')->where('payment_type','Cash')
->union($expenses)
->union($asset)
->union($liablility)
->union($equity)
->orderBy('date','DESC')->get();
 return view('daybook.cash')->with('data', $query);

}
```